# Accepting Windows start menu search result doesn't dismiss the start menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

On my Windows 10 work machine, if I press the Windows key to open the start menu, type a search term that results in a link to a directory (let's say a link named `Source` to directory `C:\WorkSource`) appearing in the results, and then either press Enter on the result or click it, Windows Explorer will open it in the background and NOT dismiss the start menu, so I have to alt-tab a bunch of times to get to it or use the mouse or something like that. When I log out of Windows and log in again, this behavior goes away for a while (i.e. if I accept the search result, the start menu goes away and I'm put in the directory in Windows explorer), but this correct behavior never persists for long. My searching so far has been fruitless. Is there something I can do to correct this? (I'm a long-time user of things like Launchy and more recently Executor, but I haven't been able to find a keyboard launcher that works to my satisfaction on Windows like my beloved LaunchBar on macOS, and I'm trying to just use the built-in Windows features, hence my desire to use the Windows search feature.)

Comment: Does this happen when [booting in Safe mode](https://www.businessinsider.fr/us/windows-10-safe-mode)?

Comment: Alas, I can't try safe mode, as I can't get past bitlocker without hassling with work helpdesk, and I'm not sure that's worth it for this.

Comment: No real resolution to this, but my workaround is to change the shortcut to launch File Explorer, passing the target directory in as an argument, something like so: `C:\Windows\explorer.exe "C:\WorkSource"`